# Can not see Kernel Image On Boot-Grub Menu Linux

Tags: kernel, kernel-module, grub, xenomai

I am trying to make a real time kernel by patching Xenomai framework: Xenomai 2.6.0 and Kernel 2.6.38.8

I patched it successfully. And was able to build the kernel:

```
make
make modules
make modules_install
make install
```

After `make install` it creates and image in `/boot` directory. But when I try `sudo update-grub`, the process gets locked, pc freezes, and when I restart the computer, I can't see that kernel image anymore.

There are no errors or warnings but I cannot see my compiler image on grub menu.

PS: I cannot see inside of `grub.cfg`, process freezes!

Comment: Instead of running `update-grub` you can simply open the grub file and edit it manually.

Comment: Can you move grub.cfg to another place (both to backup and delete) and then try update-grub? Could you open ANY files in your /boot or /boot/grub directories?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try make bzImage along with

   ```
   make clean; make modules; make modules_install; make install
   ```
2. Now execute `update-grub` command.

This will solve your problem.